# no se logro las preferencias del sistema, no hay conexión a la arquitectura

Tags: windows

Estoy homologando una aplicación a **win10**. Para **win7 x64** ejecuto el siguiente archivo .cmd para habilitar la aplicación.

```
@SET FrameworkDir=Microsoft.NET\Framework64
@SET FrameworkVersion=v2.0.50727

@set PATH=%windir%\%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%;%PATH%;

Caspol.exe -q -m -ag LocalIntranet_Zone -url "\\ruta" FullTrust -n "Transferencias.exe" -d "Transferencias.exe"
```

Pero al ejecutar la aplicación en **win10** arroja error de arquitectura.

> "No se logró las preferencias del sistema, no hay conexión a la
>   arquitectura. Se ha producido un error al crear el controlador de
>   sección de configuración para nlog: ese ensamblado no permite
>   llamadores de confianza parcial"